# Repeat tracks and repeat playlist

Tags: iphone, playlist

On iOS 8.4 why when I want to play my playlists do I have to constantly "add next" to play all the songs in that playlist? And where is the "repeat playlist" option that was there before?

Answer (score 1):

You can "REPEAT PLAYLIST" in iOS 8.4. I play my playlist on a daily basis in a repeated manner.

Do refer the User Guide for iOS 8.4 version, under page 71.

https://manuals.info.apple.com/MANUALS/1000/MA1565/en_US/iphone_user_guide.pdf

Let me know if it helps.